# Change ScrollView height dynamically on child view show/hide

Tags: android, listview, scrollview

In one of the apps I am developing, I have some data that I can display as list, on map or as analytics. User can select one of those by button click. On the screen, I have a header and below it I have a ScrollView. Within the ScrollView, I have containers for ListView, Map and Analytics. I show/hide these views based on user's action. The ListView is within ScrollView and hence I have made the ListView un-scrollable and made the expanded its height so that all items can be displayed.

Now my problem is this: Because the ListView is expanded, the ScrollView height becomes really big. Now even when I hide the ListView and show the Map instead, the ScrollView height remains the same. So even if the map is displayed in a small area, I can keep on scrolling.

Is there a way to dynamically change the height of the scrollable section.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to do this by dynamically adding/removing views. So, when I was to show the Map, I remove the ListView from the parent container and insert the Map container. This way, the height is re-calculated automatically.